Replacement the UPS APC Smart-UPS SRT 10000 battery while it's powered on?
I have an APC Smart-UPS SRT 10000 and need to replace the battery.
Would something bad happen if I replace it while it's still plugged in and powered on?
Or do I need to shut down the servers and unplug the power from the APC first before replacing the battery?
Also, If you have any documents or a link to a video demonstrating the process of replacement, please share it with me.
More details:
Model: Smart-UPS SRT 10000
SKU: SRT10KXLI
Apparent Power Rating: 10000 VA
Real Power Rating: 10000 W
Battery SKU: APCRBC140

Does your server have a dual power supply? If so, put one into the mains, pull the other out of the UPS, and your server should still be running. Then you should be able to take the UPS offline without the servers going down, potentially allowing for easier access to the UPS.

These are hot-swappable replacements. You do not need to power off the unit or disrupt operations to replace the battery cells.
Here's the replacement instruction video (in English)
